# Mockito doReturn() executes the Real function instead of just return

Tags: java, spring, mockito, powermockito

I'm trying to mock Class D constructor. yet, the mocked objects invokes the real function instead of just returning the value.

Read from bottom.

**Main**

```
public abstract class F
{
    int hi()
    {
        throw new Exception("I always throw Exception. So don't execute me");
        return 1;
    }
}


public abstract class E extends F
{
    int hi()
    {
        return super.hi();
    }
}

public class D extends E
{

}

public class C
{
    D d_object;
    C()
    {
        d_object = new new D();      // will be mocked_d!
    }

    int hi()
    {
        d_object.hi();
    }
}

public class B
{
    void fun()
    {
        C object = new C();
        int value = object.hi();
    }`
}
```

**Test**

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringJunit4ClassRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({C.class,D.class})
public class Test_B
{
    @Autowired
    A o_A;

    @Test
    public void test_method()
    {
        D mocked_D = mock(D.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(D.class).withNoArguments().then(new Answer()
        {
            @Override
            public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable
            {
                return mocked_D;
            }
        });
        PowerMockito.doReturn(2).when(mocked_d).hi();
        Assert.assertEquals(2,o_A.fun()) // throws Exception. since method inside class F gets executed.
    }
}
```

hi() method inside class F always gets invoked, hence it throws execution. I don't want to invoke that function. am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: This case is _exactly why_ dependency injection exists. Don't go through contortions trying to mock a constructor; make `D dObject` a constructor parameter for `C`. (And similar for `B`.)

Comment: I cannot change code.

Answer (score 0):

When using `@PrepareForTest` I always use `PowerMockito.mockStatic` method inside tests.